# How to use Google Drive API: "Insert File" on my personal account from a java web application

Tags: java, file-upload, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Sorry for my bad english.

I would that when a user access to my web application, my webapp uploads a file in google drive, then insert the file in google docs, then the user will show and modify the file from my page.
He downloads it and then my web application deletes the file.
In the next user access, my webapp repeats the wizard...

I have created a google account, enabled the drive api, create server key, browser key, oauth2 credential, the client_key.json, but I don't understand how my webapp can login with its account and put the file on google drive...

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

The authentication for your application will be prompted once the application is run by the user. If required, it will display a pop up for the user to consent access to his account.

You can refer to this two examples to see the implementation. [In the first example](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/java), you can see how to integrate the Drive SDK to a java project, allowing you to list the user's files. 
[The second example](https://github.com/googledrive/web-quickeditor) (javascript), provides a window running a text editor that creates a txt file. This file is stored and saved to Drive.

Comment: Thank you Rivero.
The first example have helped me more.
Now I try to upload the files that anyone can edit...